# Open a PDF in browser 2 page up view

Tags: html, pdf, embed

Is there a way to embed a pdf in a page and when it opens, to show two pages at once, side by side?

I want to simulate what happens when you open a pdf in Adobe Acrobat, then check "Two page View" and "Show cover page in Two Page view" under View->Page Display

I don't want to use a pdf reader script in my page; I'm happy if this only covers the set of users using more advanced in browser pdf readers.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do involves browsers from multiple vendors and multiple versions of it, there is no concise and succinct answer to your question.

When trying to present a PDF document to a user via the web browser, in a particular fashion, you could use the following [Parameters for Opening PDF Files](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf)

However, the parameter that you are looking for "Book View", i.e, Two Pages in a single view is not supported as per the official documentation.

**Chrome and Acrobat are no longer compatible.**
[Change in support for Acrobat and Reader plug-ins in modern web browsers](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/change-in-support-for-acrobat-and-reader-plug-ins-in-modern-web-.html)

For, other browsers that still support PDF plugins, use the following guidlines to [Display PDF in browser](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html) 
(This is mostly on the user side)

Comment: The parameters for opening PDF files link you posted was my motivation behind seeing if this kind of thing was possible.